# angular 4 persistance storage usage in promise then function

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to use angular-persistance in promise then function but always says undefined

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {PersistenceService, StorageType} from "angular-persistence";

export class ProcessingComponent implements OnInit {

  myfunc: any;

  constructor(private PersistenceService: PersistenceService ){
  }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.myfunc = new myfunction();



    this.shaObj.generateIdentity().then(function (result, PersistenceService) {
      console.log(PersistenceService.set('identityKey')); // getting undefined
    }.bind(this.PersistenceService));

  }
```

So the bind service does not seem to be working, how to get the outer scope 'this' to be passed into the '.then' function.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `this.injectableName` instead of directly using ClassName

```
console.log(PersistenceService.set('identityKey'));
```

should be

```
console.log(this.PersistenceService.set('identityKey'));
```

> **Note:** As per guideline and to avoid confusion use `cammelCase` for injected dependency

```
constructor(private persistenceService: PersistenceService ){}
```

---

Also you could use `Arrow function`'s ES6 beauty instead of using `.bind(this)`

```
this.shaObj.generateIdentity().then((result, PersistenceService) => {
  //Assuming you changed dependency name to `persistenceService`
  console.log(this.persistenceService.set('identityKey'));
});
```

Comment: winner winner, chicken dinner